# Bootstrap3 responsiveness for table is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
...
</table>
</div>
```

This code block is not resulting in responsive table in Bootstrap. Please help me in achieving the responsive table using bootstrap.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with your actual markup? it should work fine, see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/VwF6t/

Comment: i have used http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/ if this can be helpful to you

Comment: see if you have included the lib files of bootstrap correctly, check the path and process...

Comment: @SaurabhLP : I have included all the required files the responsiveness for image is working but responsiveness for table is not working. Please help me in doing this

Comment: have you included `bootstrap.js`,`bootstrap-responsive.js` and `application.js` in your template? show me what you have created...

Comment: Check if you have set the value of width for table anywhere as pixels..

Comment: @ SaurabhLP : I have downloaded the bootstrap3 files from the url ,[link](http://getbootstrap.com/) which includes bootstrap.js,bootstrap.min.js and bootsrap.css,bootstrap.min.css,bootstrap-theme.css,bootstrap-theme.min.css

Comment: Divs and tables aren't friends. Try use only tables.

Answer (score 38):

Following Responsive table will works only `<768px`.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
    </table>
</div>
```

Because `bootstrap 3` has following code

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .table-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}
```

If you want responsive table  for display `>768px`, then you can overwrite it in your css without media query just like this

```
.table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: You sir deserve a medal!
Nothing of the avobe has worked for mi except what you have posted...
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know the documentation says so which I have asked [.table-responsive doesn't work in div above the table but adding it to the table class works](https://twitter.com/charlesmudy/status/381714154182025216) ... Do the following and your issue should be solved.

**Not working:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
  ......
  </table>
</div>
```

**Works:**

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
......
</table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IMOSAVU/2/edit?html,output)

Comment: I don't think it's working, it just works as a normal (non-responsive) table. Try to resize the output panel to less than what fits in the panel's width. You can see a window scroll bar appears, not one just for the table.

Comment: @ Amitay Dobo ... when you have many columns yes but looking at the default "Not working" version, it pretty much does the same except the scroll appears inside the table which doesn't appear on the browser.

Comment: The linked demo does not work.  Even when I shrink the viewport to tiny it still just keep squishing table, not giving it a scrollbar.

Comment: I checked your demo link, and not working, but works with the first block kind of code, which is traditional way.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see why the following would not work... Make sure you are not setting widths or heights... post the full HTML.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

[bootstrap3]

Answer (score 1):

Fizer Khan's answer on this page is correct. Just to add to it though, so that you only apply this when you absolutely want it in devices >768px, I'd recommend you create a custom CSS style in your own CSS file called something like:

```
.table-responsive-force {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Then you can just use it whenever you want to actually override Bootstrap's default behaviour.

Comment: This should be a comment on @Fizer Khan's answer.

Comment: I agree with you @SamuelLindblom but this answer did help only because i wanted to apply this rule only on a couple specific tables without resorting to style tags.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't set the width to outer (wrapping) div (or section). Adding 'width: 100%' to outer element might solve the issue.